# Como verificar o número de palavras em uma String?

Tags: java, kotlin

Bom, estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade no qual preciso de identificar o número de palavras que uma string tem em Kotlin.

Do tipo :

```
texto = "Ola Mundo"
```

A variável `numeropalavra`s tem que ser igual a 2.

Existe alguma função que verifique o número de palavras, sem que eu tenha que fazer um ciclo para verificar letra a letra para descobrir o numero de palavras?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode separar a string pelos espaços entre as palavras utilizando a função `split()` e ver o tamanho (length) do array.

```
val string = "Uma string de exemplo"
val numeropalavras = string.split(" ").length
```